# How do i erase servlet variables after they are printed on the frontend

Tags: java, servlets

How do I erase the data in the servlet variable that I being displayed in the frontend?

In the code below the data is obj gets appended in multiple calls, how do I clear obj or out after it has been printed to the frontend?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 

ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String baseUrl = request.getParameter("url");
    String pageValue = request.getParameter("pageValue");
    out.println("Url ="+baseUrl+pageValue);


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    while(true)
        {
            temp = baseUrl + i;
            System.out.println(temp);
            out.println(temp);
            if(DataFunnel(temp).equals(""))
                {   
                    System.out.println("No More pages to crawl");
                    System.out.println("Stop Page Link = "+temp);
                    System.out.println("byeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
                    break;
                }
            i=i+10;
        }


    try {

        obj.put("Review-Title",  titleList);

        System.out.println(obj.get("Review-Date"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





    out.println(obj);


    out.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to 'clear' the servlets output stream.
The servlet container will close the stream after the servlet is finished.
And you also don't need to clear obj, this will made by the garbage collector after doPost is finished.